# How to implement following timer?

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, callback, thread-safety

I should implement a class that has a single thread calls all callbacks. I need a implemention help or hints.

```
1)void createTimer(const Timepoint &timepoint, const TimerCallback &callbackF);
2)void createTimer(const Millisecs & period, const TimerCallback &callbackF);
3)void createTimer(const Timepoint &timepoint, const Millisecs & period, const TimerCallback &callbackF);
```

first method : is called callbackF until timepoint.

second method : is called forever periodically.

third method : is called periodically until timepoint
Could you help how could i calls callbackF method with single thread and how can i make them synchronization with single thread?

Comment: Let me ask this.  Is it a requirement that the `callbackF` function get executed on the same thread in which createTimer is invoked on? Which is how most timer platforms work with UI threads?    Or do you just want a single dedicated thread that executes all timer callbacks regardless of which thread invoked your `createTimer` function.  Knowing this will greatly influence my answer.

Comment: It is true for your second option. I will use single thread that belongs the timerClass. The thread executes all timer callbacks regardless of which thread invoked createTimer methods according to TimePoint or Periodically.

Comment: Also, you should have TimerCallback be an std::function or allow createTimer to have have some sort of "context" parmeter that gets passed to your callback. That way, when the timer function is fired, the implementer knows for which scenario and associated objects the timer event was fired for.

Comment: using TTimerCallback = std::function<void()>; TimerCallBack is a function. Single thread is calling in different createTimer methods.

Comment: How do you plan on allowing the caller to cancel a timer?

Comment: I thought that I can use timer queue but I dont not know how 3 timer methods that work on time.